Why doesn't my grass grow evenly?
3 weeks ago I cut my grass at a higher height for the summer here in Philadelphia. Now only blades come up. I can see the 1st cut, but only a few blades grow tall now. We have had some extreme heat lately. I cut the grass once a week.
Can you explain the situation?

can you add a picture?

Question is unclear. "Now only blades come up" describes a normal lawn...

It is the norm (in nature): change of soil, deep of soil, humidity, fertilizers (and previous plants there), etc. It is common to have different height, and possibly also different species.
On lawn: it may depends on how it was generated. Machines for buildings houses, or flattering terrain, or moving soil may be a cause. or what there were in that place (a tree?). It takes nearly forever to go nearly homogeneous, if the soil was not deep enough prepared (which you should not assume from house contractors).
But also you may have utility lines (and maybe an additional dig and cover with different soil. In this case you may see some pattern (lines).
Or just randomness, e.g. different species, and because laws are reproduced vegetally (nobody keep grass get spikes and seeds), you may get patches. Mostly roundish shape, and they may growth or shrink.
Again: because it is natural way to have grass, it is difficult to find a real cause. You should investigate more, but if it seems healthy, do not worry.
